# How to remove DS_Store forever for good (not hide them but remove them)?

Tags: macos, finder, .ds-store

How do I remove and prevent from ever being created the DS_Store files on Mac OSX?

I found this article, http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/no-more-ds_store-files/, that describes preventing them from being created on network storage devices but says it doesn't work for local storage (IE my hard drive).

To be clear, I don't want to hide them, I want them not to be created.

Comment: Edit: The more I dig into operating systems and their relationship with software the more of a mess I find. Not trying to be critical but it's a f'ng mess. Rant: Full upgrades left filling up space and patches not deleted, settings and other files not removed on uninstall, application and user files saved to almost arbitrary locations, this makes backup and restore of only user files nearly impossible, no idea about permissions displayed to user on install, no permissions on demand (like in Android), no clearing of cache, no global storage cache usage organization data, etc.

Comment: One of the best things coming out of the whole mobile app store model is some organization, some accountability of applications but not all of them have crossed over to desktop operating systems.

Comment: Rant continuing: I also want to know, when I install an application, what data it's sending back home. An option to show and restrict network activity by application, an option to switch on or off encryption per application per request (with and without sending it). See the article Samsung TV sending your conversations back to it's servers (and over unencrypted networks to boot) https://www.cnet.com/news/samsungs-warning-our-smart-tvs-record-your-living-room-chatter/ then selling or giving that data away to third parties who have no obligation to protect your privacy.

Comment: The DS_Store design is proof of this mess. Rant over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you have to hack the Finder binary at runtime to prevent it from creating them. There is **no** official Apple-blessed way of doing this without directly hacking binaries.

"There's an app for that" nowadays. See [this blog](http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/) and [this code](https://github.com/snielsen/DeathToDSStore) which is quite awesome if you ask me :)